# Add an array element to an element of a JSON in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON:

```
    var json = {
      "paramh": "",
      "language":"EN",
      "modeinsert": false,
      "material": {
        "numberOfContainers": 0,
        "totalQuantity": 0,    
        "pkMaterialid": 1106,    
        "fkStoragecondid": "NORMAL",
        "materialdesc": "Desc",
        "fkMatsafety": null,
        "fkMatsop": null,
        "materialLot": [],
        "materialMember": [
          {
            "pkmaterialid": 1106,
            "pkMatclassid": "ID_Matclass"
          }
        ],
    }}
```

I have another element which is:

```
    var jsonProp =
    {
        "materialPropAssigned": [
            {
                "pkMaterialid": "1106",
                "pkMatpropid": "FLAMMABLE",
                "matpropnumvalue": "null",
                "matpropstrvalue": "Y"
            },
            {
                "pkMaterialid": "1106",
                "pkMatpropid": "HAZARDOUS",
                "matpropnumvalue": "null",
                "matpropstrvalue": "Y"
            }
        ]
    }
```

I just want to add this jsonProp inside json.material so json will be an array element of the element "material".

The result must be:

```
    var json = 
    {
      "paramh": "",
      "language":"EN",
      "modeinsert": false,
      "material": {
        "numberOfContainers": 0,
        "totalQuantity": 0,    
        "pkMaterialid": 1106,    
        "fkStoragecondid": "NORMAL",
        "materialdesc": "Desc",
        "fkMatsafety": null,
        "fkMatsop": null,
        "materialLot": [],
        "materialMember": [
          {
            "pkmaterialid": ID,
            "pkMatclassid": ID_Matclass
          }
        ],
        "materialPropAssigneds": [            
        {
            "pkMaterialid": "1106",
            "pkMatpropid": "FLAMMABLE",
            "matpropnumvalue": null,
            "matpropstrvalue": "Y"
          },
          {
            "pkMaterialid": "1106",
            "pkMatpropid": "HAZARDOUS",
            "matpropnumvalue": null,
            "matpropstrvalue": "Y"
          }      
        ]
      }
    }
```

I tried: `json.material["materialPropAssigned"]=jsonProp;`

The problem is that it creates an element inside the same element:

```
    "materialPropAssigned": {
                "materialPropAssigned": [
                    {
                        "pkMaterialid": "1106",
                        "pkMatpropid": "FLAMMABLE",
                        "matpropnumvalue": "null",
                        "matpropstrvalue": "Y"
                    }
                ]
            },
```

I cannot edit this jsonProp to eliminate the * "materialPropAssigned":* because it comes from an external part of my code.

How can I fix this?

Comment: `I have the following JSON` no!  That's just a javascript object, not JSON at all!

Comment: This is the best way to achive this json.material["materialPropAssigned"] = jsonProp.materialPropAssigned

Answer (score 0):

Well your `jsonProp` is an object with a property inside it called `materialPropAssigned`. If you assign this to `json.material["materialPropAssigned"]` that object is gonna end up in that key, not the properties of its only property.

Maybe use the spread syntax in ES6 if you wanna keep the items in the original object and override with new values?

```js
json.material["materialPropAssigned"] = {...json.material["materialPropAssigned"], ...jsonProp.materialPropAssigned}`
```

A simpler version would be to just do

```js
json.material["materialPropAssigned"] = jsonProp.materialPropAssigned
```

which would replace the whole `materialPropAssigned` property with the object you have in `jsonProp`

Depending on your use case this may also be a good thing to do, but I urge you to dig deeper into how objects work in JavaScript.

```js
json.material = {...json.material, ...jsonProp}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't assign the entire jsonProp and should just assign it's child like this:

```
json.material.materialPropAssigned = jsonProp.materialPropAssigned
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.assign(json, jsonProp )
```

The Object.assign() method copies all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It returns the modified target object.